# Removable singularity of $f(z)=\dfrac{\sin^2 z}{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am having trouble understanding when a function might have a removable singularity over a pole.

For example:
$$f(z)=\frac{\sin^2 z}{z}$$

I believe the pole is at $z=0$. However, if we take the taylor expansion of $f(z)$ apparently the pole vanishes. I do not understand how and where does the pole vanish that it becomes a removable singularity.

Comment: an isolated singularity is removable if the limit exists at that point. We can then "fill in" that point and the singuarity is removed.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{z \to 0}(z-0)\cdot f(z) =0$$ 
hence $0$ is removable singularity

this link may provide more clarity http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity

Answer (score 1):

Directly by arithmetic of limits:

$$\frac{\sin^2z}{z}=\frac{\sin z}{z}\cdot\sin z\xrightarrow [z\to 0]{} 1\cdot 0 = 0$$

which means, just as with real analysis, that the discontinuity (singularity) is removable.